# ORA-00947 : Not Enough Values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00947

I know this is a newbie question, but I really don't know what is wrong with my procedure, can anyone help me?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_COPIA_ITEM_LOCACAO
IS
TYPE TP_LOC_ITEM_BKP
IS
  TABLE OF LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO%ROWTYPE;
  LOC_BKP TP_LOC_ITEM_BKP;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO LOC_BKP FROM LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO;
  FORALL X IN LOC_BKP.FIRST..LOC_BKP.LAST
    INSERT INTO LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO_BKP  VALUES (LOC_BKP(X));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total de linha: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));

END;
```

Comment: What results are you getting? It will help greatly to clarify what error output you're getting, what you're trying to accomplish, etc. Please be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the column names :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_COPIA_ITEM_LOCACAO
IS
TYPE TP_LOC_ITEM_BKP
IS
  TABLE OF LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO%ROWTYPE;
  LOC_BKP TP_LOC_ITEM_BKP;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO LOC_BKP FROM LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO;
  FORALL X IN LOC_BKP.FIRST..LOC_BKP.LAST
    INSERT INTO LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO_BKP  VALUES (LOC_BKP(X).column_name1, LOC_BKP(X).column_name2 );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total de linha: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));

END;
/
```

[Know more here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#BABEDFJE)

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting using a record type, you omit the parentheses:

```
  FORALL X IN LOC_BKP.FIRST..LOC_BKP.LAST
    INSERT INTO LOC_ITEM_LOCACAO_BKP VALUES LOC_BKP(X);
```